# SSRS finding missing items from each merged data set

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

So I have two data sets. I use the Lookup function in `SSRS` to combine the data sets in a single `tablix`. But in my case I may have missing items in either data set. For example, I use serial number as my unique identifier. However data set 1 might have two or three serial numbers that are not in data set 2. That is easy, as the `Lookup` will just produce `NULL` so it's visible. But there is also the chance that data set 2 will have a serial number that is not in data set 1. Is there any way to display this in a single `tablix` or do I have to have two reports with each report having a `reversed lookup` into the other data set? Both data sets are created using queries from different `MS SQL Server` databases if that matters.

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot simply combine the two datasets in your dataset query?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used reporting services, but from a query standpoint, I would use common table expressions and do something like below. Probably not the solution with best performance, but it is at least very readable :)

```
CREATE TABLE #a (SerialNumber int primary key);
CREATE TABLE #b (SerialNumber int primary key);

INSERT INTO #a VALUES(1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO #b VALUES(3),(4),(5);

WITH cte_all AS (
    SELECT * FROM #a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM #b
), cte_distinct AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM cte_all
)
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.SerialNumber IS NOT NULL and b.SerialNumber IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 'Exists in both'
        WHEN a.SerialNumber IS NOT NULL and b.SerialNumber IS NULL
            THEN 'Only exists in A'
        WHEN a.SerialNumber IS NULL and b.SerialNumber IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'Only exists in B'
    END AS Comment
FROM
    cte_distinct c
    LEFT JOIN #a a ON a.SerialNumber = c.SerialNumber
    LEFT JOIN #b b ON b.SerialNumber = c.SerialNumber;

DROP TABLE #a;
DROP TABLE #b;
```

This will produce the following result:

[image: Query result]